# Is it possible to perform a nexus 2 to nexus 3 migration multiple times?

Tags: migration, nexus, sonatype

We have a nexus 2 to nexus 3 migration being done and we have A LOT of objects in our nexus 2 so the migration is somewhat slow even with the hardlink process.

The nexus documentation:
https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/upgrading.html#upgrade-process-expectations

Has this blurb:

> Using an existing installation of Nexus Repository Manager 3 populated with data and configuration as the target repository manager incurs restrictions that make the upgrade more complex and potentially requires re-configuring the version 2 instance prior to the upgrade as well as re-configuring Nexus Repository Manager 3 after the upgrade.

I'm hoping to minimize downtime so was thinking we'd do the initial migration once on a backup snapshot, then lock down access to the existing Nexus 2 server, re-sync the snapshot to the latest data and then do the migration a second time (with the hopes that the second migration should be faster since)

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, will this actually decrease the downtime or will it attempt to reprocess the same files again?

The blurb is not entirely clear what makes this more complex and why it requires re-configuring the version 2 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible but it is not really supported. The upgrade is incremental and can be done while the app is still running and serving users and continues to sync content. As such you can minimize downtime already.

Comment: So while the migration is being done, it will pick up new changes to the previous nexus 2?

Comment: I missed this part of the upgrade doc:
The status in the view shows the number of components transferred and when the last changes where detected in version 2. Once all components are migrated and no further changes have been detected for a while the upgrade is mostly complete. You can now decide upon waiting for further deployments to version 2 or finalizing the upgrade. To finalize, stop the monitoring and proceed through the Finishing screen.

So based on that and what you're saying, the upgrade will actually incrementally watch for changes until finalized.  That probably would work.

Comment: Yes.. thats the whole intent... so you might want to accept my answer.